# CONVERT into a specific culture DATETIME without using FORMAT

Tags: sql-server

I would like to change datetime in SQL Server using `CONVERT` with style 113.

(click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) for more info)

But I want it to be culture specific. Especially in Indonesian (id-id), without using `FORMAT` (click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) for more info) and only using `CONVERT`.

For example, for date **05 August 2018 18:21:35:743**, the desired result is:

```
05 Agt 2018 18:21:35:743
```

While in reality, the result is:

```
05 Aug 2018 18:21:35:743
```

Notice the month difference (Agt and Aug). The desired result is in Indonesian, while the second result is in Europe standard.

I have tried using `FORMAT`, but is there anyway using only `CONVERT` instead of `FORMAT`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in SQL Server. If you have front-end such as C#, VB, there you can do it like this : https://ideone.com/cy9eG0

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support this language natively, so your option for doing this in T-SQL is to simply take the 113 output and do 12 replaces, switching out `Aug` with `Agt`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little ugly, but I would still go with Format() if available

I don't know the Indonesian months, hence the mth1...Agt...mth12

**Example**

```
Declare @D datetime ='05 August 2018 18:21:35:743'

Select left(convert(varchar(50),@D,113),3)
      +choose(datepart(MONTH,@D),'mth1','mtn2','mth3','mth4','mth5','mth6','mth7','Agt','mth9','mth10','mth11','mth12')
      +right(convert(varchar(50),@D,113),18)
```

**Returns**

```
05 Agt 2018 18:21:35:743
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know there's CHOOSE in T-SQL. Edit: Thanks for the help!